# How to find out the process which is allocated to a specific port in windows 11

Tags: docker, powershell

I would like to start a docker container up.

However the Power shell console says . port is already allocated

```
> docker-compose up -d
[+] Running 0/1
 - Container node  Starting                                                                                        0.2s
Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint node (c8654a89ce1rr34dbc560324b76f97b35cfd8be259b8f8011269a): Bind for 0.0.0.0:3000 failed: port is already allocated
```

I tried this

```
 netstat -ao | find "3000"
```

However, nothing responded.

```
> netstat    -ano



  Protocol   Local adress      external           Status            PID
  TCP         0.0.0.0:135            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       1576
  TCP         0.0.0.0:445            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4
  TCP         0.0.0.0:5040           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       8800
  TCP         0.0.0.0:6646           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       7696
  TCP         0.0.0.0:7680           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       11580
  TCP         0.0.0.0:17500          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       11492
  TCP         0.0.0.0:38383          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       308
  TCP         0.0.0.0:49664          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       1200
  TCP         0.0.0.0:49665          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       1100
  TCP         0.0.0.0:49666          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       2068
```

Comment: Check if it's an exited docker container using `docker ps -a`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your connection is using TCP you can use `Get-NetTCPConnection` to get more information about that port which displays a property of OwningProcess. This is the process ID you can use to get the process name from `Get-Process`.

```
Get-Process -Id (
    (Get-NetTCPConnection -LocalPort 3000).OwningProcess
) | Select-Object -ExpandProperty ProcessName
```